# Browser shows repeating datetime values after DST change

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I am trying to display some datatime values in the a data table, here is the example code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,0,0,0));
        console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,1,0,0));
        console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,2,0,0));
        console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,3,0,0));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

the browser shows repeating values for 2 AM.
Here is the log output

```
Sun Mar 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Sun Mar 26 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Sun Mar 26 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) **(Should it not be 3am)**
Sun Mar 26 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) **(Should it not be 4am)**
```

I know I can use Date.UTC()

```
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2017,2,26,0,0,0)));
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2017,2,26,1,0,0)));
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2017,2,26,2,0,0)));
console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(2017,2,26,3,0,0)));
```

But that will display wrong date time values in other time zones.
Can someone suggest a solution to this problem? Or can someone explain what is happening here...?

Comment: That would most likely be because "1 AM March 26th 2017" doesn't exist. That entire hour is skipped, by moving the clocks forward. So when you request that time from the JavaScript engine, it "corrects" it by moving you forward an hour, since that's what happened to that hour. This is why, instead of manipulating date parts, you should work with timestamps. Increment the timestamp by your interval amount and see what date/time you end up with.

Comment: I would use a unix timestamp (UTC), do all calculations, then put it into the appropriate timezone. As @NiettheDarkAbsol, points out, the output you saw is to be expected.

Comment: i don't see a propblem. in GMT+1 date is in fact chagned due to daylight saving and @NiettheDarkAbsol is absolutely right. . what are you trying to acommplish? stick to simple rule: create and manipulate datetime in timestamp/utc, then display in any correct zone.

Comment: I am simply trying to display some data in a data table see this.... https://jsfiddle.net/rishad/cd24m7ys/

Comment: My question is if 
`console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,1,0,0)); -> Sun Mar 26 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`
then why 
`console.log(new Date(2017,2,26,2,0,0)); -> Sun Mar 26 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`... Should it not be 3AM (GMT+1) ??

Comment: @Ali: https://jsfiddle.net/cd24m7ys/1/

Comment: @Ali:  `Should it not be 3AM (GMT+1)?` no. you create time using saving time, the fact you are even trying to create invalid date should throw error but javascript is polite enought to try fix the error for you

Comment: you must understand `2017-03-26 01:00 GMT +1` **doesn't exists in our world**. this is main error

Comment: @Peter, how about countries that do not observe daylight saving time https://sleep.org/articles/does-everyone-observe-daylight-saving/?

Comment: @Peter thanks for the `jsfiddle` but my data is not always continuous so I cannot  add time interval... what I think I should do is, parse the datatime in UTC then send it to the client and use `Date.UTC()`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior depends on where time zone that is currently set on your computer is participating in daylight savings time [Does Everyone Observe Daylight Saving Time?](https://sleep.org/articles/does-everyone-observe-daylight-saving/)

If you switch you locale to Iceland time zone, for instance, `(UTC+00:00) Monrovia, Rejkjavik` and execute the code in console:

```
new Date(2017,2,26,0,0,0)
new Date(2017,2,26,1,0,0)
new Date(2017,2,26,2,0,0)
new Date(2017,2,26,3,0,0)
```

You will see the output where all hours are observed:

```
Sun Mar 26 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Standard Time)
Sun Mar 26 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Standard Time)
Sun Mar 26 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Standard Time)
Sun Mar 26 2017 03:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Standard Time)
```

For countries that do participate in daylight savings one our will be missing depending on their timezone.

You could also check `(UTC+10:00) Brisbane`, Australia you see that all hours from midnight of 26th to midnight of 27th of March are displayed correctly.

Comment: That is correct... I already tested it for different timezones... as @NiettheDarkAbsol said, in British Summer Time `2017-03-26 01:00:00` does not exist so JavaScript engine "corrects" it by moving it forward an hour instead of throwing an exception. Javascript is being `polite` to me :D

Comment: That's right, somehow I missed that very first comment :)

Answer (score -2):

If you can use libraries I highly recomend you to use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), it will make your life easier.

```
console.log(moment("2017-02-26 00:00:00").format());  
console.log(moment("2017-02-26 01:00:00").format());  
console.log(moment("2017-02-26 02:00:00").format());  
console.log(moment("2017-02-26 03:00:00").format());
```